# How to break out/export callback functions depending on previous variables

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

## How to break out/export callback functions depending on previous variables

I want to know how it is possible to successfully break out callback functions relying on previously defined variables. Currently, my code is looking like a "callback hell" because I am not familiar with good strategies on how to break out and structure callbacks.

### Prerequisite

Consider the following code using a large callback function:

```
MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODBINST,
    (err, db) => {
        assert.equal(null, err)
        console.log("Connected successfully to database.")

        app.get(
            "/",
            (req, res) => {
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
            }
        )

        app.get(
            "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
            async (req, res) => {
                const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                                           .find({"state": "open"})
                                           .count()
                res.send({issuesOpen})
            }
        )
    }
)
```

How do I break out the individual routes (`app.get()`)? Let me walk you through different situations.

### Situation 1: Breaking out the entire callback (this works)

```
const entireCallback = (err, db) => {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log("Connected successfully to database.")

    app.get(
        "/",
        (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
        }
    )

    app.get(
        "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
        async (req, res) => {
            const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                                        .find({"state": "open"})
                                        .count()
            res.send({issuesOpen})
        }
    )
}

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODBINST,
    entireCallback
)
```

### Situation 2: Breaking out further - This does not work

But it is not possible for me to break this out into even further small functions since the second route `/api/AmountIssuesOpen` depends on the variable `db`.

```
const _indexRoute = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
}

const _AmountIssuesOpenRoute = async (req, res) => {
    const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                                .find({"state": "open"})
                                .count()
    res.send({issuesOpen})
}

const entireCallback = (err, db) => {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log("Connected successfully to database.")

    // This works because the index Route is not dependent on `db`
    app.get(
        "/",
        _indexRoute
    )

    // This does not work because `db` is undefined
    app.get(
        "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
        _AmountIssuesOpenRoute
    )
}

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODBINST,
    entireCallback
)
```

The issue with `_AmountIssuesOpenRoute` is that `db` is undefined. It also doesn't help if I would pass in `db` as argument, like here:

```
const _AmountIssuesOpenRoute = async (req, res, db) => {
    const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                                .find({"state": "open"})
                                .count()
    res.send({issuesOpen})
}
```

### Situation 3: Could you even break out the entire app.get() routes?

Would it even be possible to break out the entire `app.get()` functions? How would I just have them in a different file and simply pass into the `MongoClient.connect()` callback?

```
const _completeIndexRoute = () => {
    app.get(
        "/",
        (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
        }
    )
}

const _completeAmountIssuesOpenRoute = () => {
    app.get(
        "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
        async (req, res) => {
            const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                                        .find({"state": "open"})
                                        .count()
            res.send({issuesOpen})
        }
    )
}

const entireCallback = (err, db) => {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log("Connected successfully to database.")

    _completeIndexRoute
    _competeAmountIssuesOpenRoute        
}

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.MONGODBINST,
    entireCallback
)
```

Comment: The last one seems to be the simplest. No just *call* those `_complete…Route` function, and make sure to pass them the `db` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding some promises (could be implemented using `async` `await`) helps a little.

```
function connect(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(
            process.env.MONGODBINST,
            (err, db) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(db);
            }
        );
    });
}

let gotDB = connect();
gotDB.then(db => {
    console.log("Connected successfully to database.")
    app.get(
        "/",
        (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
        }
    )

    app.get(
        "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
        async (req, res) => {
            const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                .find({"state": "open"})
                .count()
            res.send({issuesOpen})
        }
    )
}).catch(err => {
    console.error("Could not connect to the database", err);
});
```

the same code using `async/await`:

```
async function connect(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(
            process.env.MONGODBINST,
            (err, db) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(db);
            }
        );
    });
}

try {
    let db = await connect();
    console.log("Connected successfully to database.")
    app.get(
        "/",
        (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "./../public/index.html"))
        }
    )

    app.get(
        "/api/AmountIssuesOpen",
        async (req, res) => {
            const issuesOpen = await db.collection("GHISSUES")
                .find({"state": "open"})
                .count()
            res.send({issuesOpen})
        }
    )
} catch {
    console.error("Could not connect to the database", err);
};
```